# How much sugar is in my UHT Milk?

Tags: nutrition, sugar, milk

Many forms of UHT milk contain sugar, however, the packaging I have does not give a specific gram content. But they do give a percentage of sugar in the ingredients section. Can I calculate the amount of grams of sugar using this example below?

1 liter of milk contains 2.8% sugar.

1 liter = 1000 grams

1000 grams x .028 = 28 grams

Therefore 28 grams of sugar per 1 liter of milk?

If 100ml of milk equals one serving, then there are 2.8 grams of sugar per serving?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to know how much sugar is in the milk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is incorrect. Liters are a measure of volume but grams are a measure of weight, so you need to convert 1 liter of milk to the ***weight*** of 1 liter of milk. (Your calculations would be correct for water, by the way.)

Milk is an organic product so some variation is going to exist, but 1 liter of whole milk [weighs approximately 1031 grams](http://www.aqua-calc.com/calculate/food-volume-to-weight).

From that point forward the rest of your calculations are correct:

1031 grams x .028 = 28.8 grams of sugar per liter of milk

If 100 ml is one serving, then each serving contains 2.88 grams of sugar.

In other words, you were low by about 1 gram.